# silverlight redirect to login page

Tags: silverlight, redirect, logout

I have a silverlight app where the users what a logout timer.

So I use a timer and then after 10 mins i call

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(loginPageUrl));
```

But the user can still just use the Back Arrow to return to the silverlight app.

Is there any way to prevent that?

I have added some code to the asp page, as below, but that does not seem to help.

```
Response.Expires = -1;
Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "No-Cache");        
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
```

Any idea's or other suggestions?

Comment: Does the page that hosts your silverlight page check the authorization of the User? Another question: Could they just bookmark the URL of the silverlight page and return to it without logging in?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution in keeping with your current approach would be to have your timer run every 5 seconds and then do something like this:

```
if(IsSessionExpired)
{
   HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(loginPageUrl));
}
```

This will redirect them within 5 seconds of them hitting the back button...